# adb shell install -g to grant all runtime permissions automatically when installing an APK via USB: Error "install: Needs 1 argument"

Tags: android, apk, adb, android-permissions

Official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#test-grant-all says:

> To grant all runtime permissions automatically when you install an app on an emulator or test device, use the **-g** option for the adb shell install command, as demonstrated in the following code snippet:
> `adb shell install -g PATH_TO_APK_FILE`

On my computer with an Android 13 device connected via USB, when I run `adb shell install -g my.apk`, I get this error: `install: Needs 1 argument`

Same error after running this:

```
adb push my.apk /sdcard
adb shell
cd /sdcard
install -g my.apk
```

By the way I also get error `install: Needs 2 arguments` when I remove the `-g`.
`adb install -g my.apk` does not throw any error but I would rather use what the documentation says.

Am I missing something, or is the documentation wrong?
How to correctly grant all runtime permissions automatically when I install an APK via USB?

---

Documentation screenshot:

[image]

Comment: On my Pixel 4 phone running Android 13 the install command shows the help `-g Make copy belong to GROUP`. The option to grant run-time permission is only present in `adb install` command, not `adb shell install`. If you want to understand what happens when you execute `adb install -g app.apk` start Wireshark and sniff the adb communication.

Answer (score 2):

```
adb install -g [APK Path]
```

This worked for me. From the documentation https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#issuingcommands

> -g: Grant all permissions listed in the app manifest.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer! It references the documentation directly to the question. Worked for me (Android 11 Go, adb 1.0.41)! Good to be able to grant the permissions in the same command as the `install`.